# Is it possible to import IsMasterLanguage field from CSV file in UI import articles feature in salesforce lightning?

Tags: knowledge, csv, import, articles, lightning-knowledge

Hi guys I am  trying to import salesforce knowledge articles from CSV file however I am getting an error that displays IsMasterLanguage column in the header cannot be mapped. So I wanted to know whether this field could be imported from a CSV file as I went through various documentation but couldn't get any related content to my doubt.
Anyone having an idea on this?

Comment: do you have translations?

Comment: The CSV file importing is having a particular language translation only not the primary article. @KrisGoncalves